# Delete Entirerow only if row is blank otherwise if any row contains any data remains

Tags: vba, excel, row

Hi I am working on VBA Code that goes through all my data and only deletes an entire row if it is blank.  Therefore once the blank row is deleted, the row shift up.

However, in case I have one row that contains some data. I want that row to remain unchanged.

All the examples i have seen out there delete an entire row even if it has some data in the row. and Some of them delete the row but does not remove the row so that cells shift up.

Please help me out.

Comment: *"All the solutions out there"* - Can you include such a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following-

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteBlankRow()
    Dim i As Long

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    '//- Turn off calculation and screenupdating.
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
            '//- Work backwards because we are deleting rows.
            For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
                    Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next i
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this algorithm:
1) find the last row which is contains any value;
2) execute the loop through the rows with counting of the values in row and delete row in case when count of values in row is equal to zero, it can looks like the example below:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()
    Dim i&: i = Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    While i <> 0
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(i)) = 0 Then Rows(i).Delete
        i = i - 1
    Wend
End Sub
```